# Taharot tag: masechta or seder?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, specific-tag

The [masechet-taharot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-taharot) tag seems to be referring to *seder* Taharos, instead of the masechta included in it with the same name. (It seems that way because there is no "masechta" tag for each individual masechta in Taharos — I tried a few different spellings of "Keilim" and came up with nothing. Also, the only question on it so far is about the seder.

I didn't think it would be appropriate as a tag synonym, since Maseches Taharos and Seder Taharos are certainly not the same thing (though tags like [denominations](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denominations) and [heterodox](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heterodox) did get a little confused).

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/996/759

Comment: Detagged [meta-tag:feature-request] as this is not a request for new site functionality or the like.

Answer (score 2):

The one question with [masechet-taharot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-taharot) was [Why aren't Zeraim or Toharos included in the Bavli as Mishnayos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18597), and I've retagged it to have [seder-taharot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seder-taharot) since, as you note, it's more appropriate to the question. (You coulda done it yourself.)

Comment: It's true that I could have retagged it, but I was thinking more along the lines of *renaming* it, since apparently we don't have tags for non-Bavli masechtos.

Comment: I guess the other option is making a tag for every masechta.

Comment: @ba I don't think there is a rule about non-Bavli masechtot. Tags just get made as they come up, and for better or for worse we haven't had a whole bunch of Taharot related questions on the site.

Comment: The [systematic list of tags](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/996/systematic-list-of-tags) shows that many maseschot, and for that matter many parshiyot, are missing from the tag set.  They get created as needed, so please do create new ones when they come up.

Comment: The tag has self-destructed. Should we nuke this whole question?

Comment: @DoubleAA, [done](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/1345/revisions).